# passport authentication failure leads to redirect loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I am using node, express and passport with facebook authentication.
I have the following routes (when `/facebook/auth/callback` is the callback url):

```
function render(page, req, res) {
    var user = null;
    if (req.user) {
        user = req.user.toObject();
        user.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
    res.render(page, { user: user });
}
app.get('/auth-failure', function (req, res) {
    res.render('auth-failure');
});
app.get('/auth-success', function (req, res) {
    render('auth-success', req, res);
});
app.get('/facebook/auth', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: [ 'email', 'user_about_me', 'publish_actions']}));
app.get('/facebook/auth/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth-failure', successRedirect: '/auth-success' }));
```

When the authentication succeeded I got the page `auth-success` view as I expected. But when the authentication failed and facebook returns to:
    [http://localhost:3000/facebook/auth/callback?error_code=2102&error_message=User+is+not+a+test+user+owned+by+the+application#*=*](http://localhost:3000/facebook/auth/callback?error_code=2102&error_message=User+is+not+a+test+user+owned+by+the+application#_=_)

I don't get the `auth-failure` view! Instead, firefox returns me the page:

[image]

When running in chrome, I get the message:
[image]

I try to check things and I replace the failure router to:

```
app.get('/facebook/auth/callback', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/auth-failure');
});
```

And this rendered the `auth-failure` view successfully.
What is the problem with the passport.js facebook failure authentication?
Why does it returns me that error page?

**Regarding to @Matt Bakaitis comment:**
Here is me serialize and deserialize functions:

```
// serialize sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({ _id: id }, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: It appears the example works in Firefox though.

Comment: @toiletfreak: I attached image of this wrong behavior in Firefox.

Comment: Did you change the passport.serialize or passport.deserialize code?

Comment: You can try using a virtual host entry instead of localhost something like: local.example.com . Many Facebook sdks face errors when used with localhost.

Comment: @Matt Bakaitis: I added my serialize and deserialize code

Comment: @Jaspal Singh: Can you explain more how?

Comment: You need to add entry to httpd-vhosts.conf and (if using windows) hosts file. There are hundreds of guides online for it that you can refer. simply put in hosts file add "127.0.0.1      local.example.com" at the end, in httpd-vhosts.conf add en entry like "<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName local.example.com
 ServerAlias local.example.com
 DocumentRoot E:/gd/xampp/htdocs/example/
 <Directory E:/gd/xampp/htdocs/example/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>" and restart apache.

Comment: Hi Naor, were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you are using a custom callback and need to provide a res object like....

```
 app.get('/facebook/auth/callback', function(req, res, next) { 
         passport.authenticate('facebook',..............
```

Answer (score 1):

I would fire up [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see what exactly is sent over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Doing more research, because I also use passport.js to integrate with a facebook (and others), it looks like this might already be an [open issue](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth/issues/16) reported for the passport-oauth (which passport-facebook uses).

The person logging the problem had a workaround for the error check on [line 98 of the oauth2 code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth/blob/master/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth2.js) :

```
    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
            , function(req, res, next) {
                  if (req.query && !req.query.error && req.query.error_code) {
                      req.query.error = true;
                  }
                  next();
            }
            , passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth-failure', successRedirect: '/auth-success' }
     );
```

For good measure, it's also a good idea to double-check your settings on Facebook and that your localhost is listed in the right location(s). Also, check to be sure that everything matches perfectly in Node.js.  I had issues with passport-twitter when I made a typo in my configuration strings that was very hard to catch as it didn't throw an error in Node.js but caused my auth to fail in a difficult way to catch.  Here are a few links with people who had the same `error_message` as you and they seem to indicate facebook-side configuration issues:

- [redirect_uri is not owned by the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594310/redirect-uri-is-not-owned-by-the-application)
- [Facebook login, redirect_uri is not owned by the application. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835014/facebook-login-redirect-uri-is-not-owned-by-the-application-why)
- [facebook oauth api login problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381903/facebook-oauth-api-login-problems)

Comment: There is an error in the code? It is missing a parenthesis or something of the like?