# passportjs get authentication error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passportjs for facebook authentication. Here is my facebook strategy:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOne({ 'facebook.id': profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                user = new User({
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    email: profile.emails[0].value,
                    username: profile.username,
                    provider: 'facebook',
                    facebook: profile._json
                });
                user.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    return done(err, user);
                });
            } else {
                return done(err, user);
            }
        });
    }));
```

I added the following routes:

```
app.get('/facebook/auth', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: [ 'email', 'user_about_me', 'publish_actions']}), function(req, res) { });

// I need the following fix due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17015836/289246
app.get('/facebook/auth/callback', function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.query && !req.query.error && req.query.error_code) {
            req.query.error = true;
        }
        next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/facebook-auth-failure', successRedirect: '/auth-success', failureFlash: true })
);

app.get('/facebook-auth-failure', users.authFailure);
app.get('/auth-success', users.authSuccess);
```

My users.authFailure method is:

```
exports.authFailure = function (req, res) {
    var error = ??? 
    // How can I get here the error message??
    res.render('auth-failure', {
        error: error || 'An error has accured'
    });
};
```

In case of facebook authentication failure, how can I get the error message (I want to display it to the user)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `failureFlash`, this should do it:

```
var error = req.flash('error');
```

Comment: When I add `console.log(req.flash('error'));` to the authFailure handler, it prints me `[]` and not the error. Any idea?

Comment: @Naor flash messages are stored in the users' session, perhaps your session is expiring too soon? A good way to debug Passport is to use a custom callback as described [on this page](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) (search for 'Custom Callback')

Answer (score 0):

I experienced many many problems and bugs and configurations issues during working with Passport. My solution was to move to Everyauth.

Comment: too bad, I've used Passport for several projects and it has always worked just fine for me :)

Comment: @robertklep: Have you used it with facebook? I don't have high demands, only simple login and it failed more than once.

Comment: not Facebook, but I've used the Google and Local strategies just fine. I have to admit that you have to 'get' Passport before everything makes sense, and `everyauth` looks very mature too :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be any use to you but I got access to flash messages this way.
When you are defining the FacebookStrategy use the passReqToCallback parameter.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
   clientID: facebook.getClientID(),
   clientSecret: facebook.getClientSecret(),
   callbackURL: facebook.getCallback(),
   passReqToCallback: true
```

this will allow you to add the req.flash() as a parameter to the done() like so

return done(false, user, reg.flash('success', 'Sign in successfull'));

Hope that sheds some light on the situation for you or anybody else looking for help